# Error: “gzip: stdout: No space left on device” during Linux kernel upgrade (while there is space)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, kernel

Moving this over here to try and garner some insight.

I'm currently in the process of trying to upgrade my Linux kernel from 4.4.0-63 to 4.10.12 (I have made some edits to the files here). I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64 and I've gotten through the steps of: make menuconfig (I accepted the defaults) -> make -> make modules -> make modules_install

Though once I try to do "make install" I get the following error:

```
user@thiscomp:/usr/src/linux-4.10.12$ sudo make install
sh ./arch/x86/boot/install.sh 4.10.12 arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
        System.map "/boot"
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.10.12 
/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.12
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.10.12 
/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.12
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.10.12
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/ast_dp501_fw.bin for module ast

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.10.12 with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

First, I checked to see if /boot was full, but it seemed like it wasn't:

```
user@thiscomp:/usr/src/linux-4.10.12$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  1.2M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/dm-0       252G   43G  197G  18% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             16G  152K   16G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   32K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1       236M   75M  149M  34% /boot
```

From what I've seen online, this usually has to do with past kernel versions s ticking around longer than they need to. Though, from what I was able to see, there weren't past versions hanging out after running "dpkg -l linux-image*":

```
un  linux-image     
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-63-generic  
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-63-generic
ii  linux-image-generic-lts-xenial
```

Finally, there weren't any errors installing into tmpfs:

```
user@thiscomp:/usr/src/linux-4.10.12$ sudo mount -t tmpfs none /boot
user@thiscomp:/usr/src/linux-4.10.12$ sudo make install
sh ./arch/x86/boot/install.sh 4.10.12 arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
        System.map "/boot"
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.10.12         
/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.12
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.10.12                 
/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.12
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.10.12
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/ast_dp501_fw.bin for module ast
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.10.12 /boot/vmlinuz-
4.10.12
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.10.12 
/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.12
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.10.12 
/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.12
user@thiscomp:/usr/src/linux-4.10.12$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  1.2M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/dm-0       252G   43G  197G  18% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             16G  152K   16G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   32K  100M   1% /run/user
none             16G  310M   16G   2% /boot
```

I'm not sure where else to look to figure out the problem (especially since it seems like /boot isn't full). Is there anyway to make the installation smaller while still installing what is necessary (or a way to resize /boot without wiping the system?).

***edit*** (To add comment requested commands):

```
user@thiscomp:/usr/src/linux-4.10.12$ df -i
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            4108437    534  4107903    1% /dev
tmpfs           4113275    609  4112666    1% /run
/dev/dm-0      16777216 470608 16306608    3% /
none            4113275     14  4113261    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            4113275      6  4113269    1% /run/lock
none            4113275      6  4113269    1% /run/shm
none            4113275     25  4113250    1% /run/user
/dev/sda1         62248    307    61941    1% /boot
```

**edit2**Adding File sizes after mounting tmpfs:

```
user@thiscomp:/usr/src/linux-4.10.12$ ls -l /boot/initrd.img-4.10.12 
/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.12 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 312429420 Apr 26 07:02 /boot/initrd.img-4.10.12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7149280 Apr 26 07:01 /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.12
```

**edit3** Module counts:

```
user@thiscomp:/usr/src/linux-4.10.12$ grep -o '=m' /boot/config-4.4.0-63-
generic | wc -l
4409
user@thiscomp:/usr/src/linux-4.10.12$ grep -o '=m' .config | wc -l
4332
```

Comment: please [edit] your question and provide the full output of `df -h`

Comment: Edited. Apologies, elsewhere they had asked me to remove the extra information from df -h

Comment: Your filesystem may be out of inodes. Please [edit] your question and add the output  of  'df -i'

Comment: edited and updated

Comment: What are the sizes of the files generated when you mount the tmpfs, including the size of the `/boot/initrd.img-4.10.12`? Can you copy those files manually from the tmpfs somewhere else, unmount the tmpfs, and then copy them to `/boot/`?

Comment: I added the file sizes. When I try to do what you said (mount tmpfs, copy the files somewhere else, unmount tmpfs, copy to /boot/) I get that there is no space left on the device.

Comment: It seems that this image (initrd.img-4.10.12:312,429,420) is significantly larger than my current one (initrd.img-4.4.0-63-generic:35,960,364)

Comment: Are you sure you properly set up the kernel? How big is `/lib/modules/4.10.12`?

Comment: When I ran the configuration (make menuconfig) I accepted all of the defaults without changing anything. Is it possible that it installed a much larger version? If so, is there a better way to make sure the config file is correct?

Comment: When I check for how many modules are in my current config file when compared to the one im trying to use for 4.10.12, there are more modules in my current one: (see edit above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem ended  up being that I didn't strip the modules before running make_install, so the kernel that was being installed was huge in comparison to my current kernel (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43624752/3776230)

Basically, had to run make "make INSTALL_MOD_STRIP=1 modules_install" when installing the modules.